# Flushing a socket after performing a socket_write in PHP

Tags: php, sockets

I have the following code:

```
foreach ($this->_queue as $header)
{
    $result = socket_write($this->_socket, $header, strlen($header));
    if (!$result)
    {
        // check error here if result was false
    }
}
socket_close($this->_socket);
```

This code works fine-ish in that it will generally reach the third iteration of the foreach, after which it breaks out completely (doesn't even reach the `socket_close($this->_socket)` line).

I suspect that I need to do something like flush the socket (force it to write and then clean itself or *something*) but I have not found anywhere that indicates if this is possible.

Would it be better to simply open and close a socket for each iteration through `$this->_queue`?

Comment: You're closing the socket within the loop.  Each iteration after the first should end up returning an error due to a closed socket.

Comment: Apologies! I edited my example to accurately reflect the code I have right now. Closing the socket in the loop was part of a fix I'm trying out :)

Comment: You are aware that not all the data may be written at once? see [socket_write — Write to a socket](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-write.php). imo, Don't assume it will be. The way to do this is to have a loop and accumulate the total length sent until all the data is sent or it returns zero.

Comment: @RyanVincent How would you suggest I go about writing said loop? I'm struggling to think of how I'd do that.

Comment: example code: http://pastebin.com/FDczzQPN. I have full working classes I can make available if you wish - I did them for another question on SO.

Comment: Thanks! No need to make other classes available, I think :) The amount of data I send at a time is very rarely more than 430 bytes at a time, but I will use your example to add a definite check to make sure all the data is written for sure. One question about your code: where are you getting `$outLen` from?

Comment: It is the remaining length of the message to send. i.e. $msgLen  - $written

Comment: Cool, I'll make some changes to my code and then let it fly.